# Can you spot people in BF3 when you are in a vehicle?

Tags: battlefield-3

Say you are flying a heli, can you use the same spot key/button to spot people on the ground?  Do you have to have them in your sights?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. The same principle applies as when you are on foot, in that you need to be looking in their direction and not have them in your peripheral vision. The same applies to all vehicles.